# Prove f is differentiable in 0 for $\alpha > 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Question:**
> Let$ f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be homogenous of degree $\alpha > 0$ and let $f(0) = 0$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable in $0$ for $\alpha > 1$ with derivative equal to $0$

I am using the definition of the total derivative. $f$ is differentiable in $a$ with derivative $A$ if the following holds.

$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-A(h)}{||h||} = 0
$$

So I think I have to prove the following:
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)-A(h)}{||h||} = 0
$$

Take $h = tx$
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(tx)-A(tx)}{||tx||} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{tf(x)-tA(x)}{t||x||} = \frac{f(x)-A(x)}{||x||}.
$$
And here is where I got stuck. I would think that $f = A$ so the limit equals $0$ but how do I show that $A = 0$, because the derivative needs to be equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homogeneous of degree $\alpha$ means $f(tx) = t^\alpha f(x)$ for every $t\geq 0$. Replace that in your computations and you should get your answer.